# Расстановка знаков препинания в заголовке

Tags: пунктуация, тире, двоеточие, заголовок

> Анри: посмотрел повтор гола Ибрагимовича и подумал — ну да, это же Златан

Это заголовок спортивной новости (на отсутствие кавычек при прямой речи не обращайте внимания — это ноу-хау сайта).
Вопрос: корректно ли употребление тире или все же после глагола "подумал" необходимо двоеточие?

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, тире поставили от безвыходности, чтобы два двоеточия не путали читателя, но если слова Анри начать с прописной, то второе двоеточие можно поставить:

**Анри: Посмотрел повтор гола Ибрагимовича и подумал: ну да, это же Златан!**

Примечание. Для выразительности добавлен восклицательный знак.

Answer (score 0):

Высказывание  оформлено как **бессоюзное сложное предложение**, при этом **постановка тире вместо обычного двоеточия допускается.**

Интонационно  это выглядит **как отсутствие предупредительной паузы**, характерной для двоеточия, что соответствует этой речевой ситуации.

Розенталь: http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=151#pp1517.

Перед второй частью бессоюзного сложного предложения ставится тире, если она (нередко — неполное предложение) имеет **изъяснительное значение** (перед ней можно вставить союз что), **причем в первой части не содержится интонационного предупреждения о последующем изложении какого-либо факта**: Иногда мне думается — надо убежать (М. Г.); Овца же говорит — она всю ночь спала (Кр.);  Но вижу — не слушает она меня;

Comment: Если поставим *что*, выглядеть это будет "не очень": *что ну да...*

Comment: Да и предупредительная пауза здесь "слышна".

Comment: Подстановка - это  только формальный прием,  который определяет изъяснительный характер второго предложения. Практически варианты с тире и двоеточием различаются интонационно, о чем и говорит Розенталь.

Comment: Предупредительная пауза - это подчеркнутая остановка  речи,  а ритм нашей жизни, как и речевой ритм, к паузам не склонен. Поэтому двоеточие всё чаще ставится там, где его нельзя заменить тире.